# Cycle Routing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4, multimodal-network

I'm currently working on a project based around cycling. I need to know which dataset I should get hold of which will allow me to create a multimodal network in Network Analyst so that when I run the network, cycle paths such as the National Cycle Network are also utilised by bikes. I have been using OSM data for networking, but i'm unsure if this can be integrated with a cycle network.

What dataset would provide me with the information I require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenStreetMap is probably the best cycling geodataset in the world - I use it for the routing at http://cycle.travel/map, for example.

However, you may need some degree of experience with processing OSM data to use it. Signposted cycle routes such as the National Cycle Network are stored as 'route relations'. These are unlikely to be preserved in the shapefiles that are commonly available for download, so you'll need to work with raw OSM data (in .osm.xml or .osm.pbf format) or export it from a site such as Overpass Turbo. (I don't have any ArcGIS experience so can't assist with getting it into ArcGIS, I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Edina Digimap, 'ITN Urban Paths' provides data for urban walking and cycling routes. Once downloaded, it's used the same as ITN.

Comment: It does help! Are you aware of any open source data that would also contain this information?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, sorry!